# Graph chromatic number and graph homomorphism?

Tags: graph-theory

For two graphs G and H such that $\chi(G) < \chi(H)$, then is it true that there always exist a graph homomorphism from G to H ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $G$ be a triangle and $H$ the [Grötzsch graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch_graph).
Then $\chi(G)=3$, $\chi(H)=4$ and since $H$ has no triangle, there is no homomorphism from $G$ to $H$.

[image: Source: Wikipedia,en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Groetzsch-graph.svg]

Comment: Thanks Hagen von eitzen.  Is it also true that for any m , we can construct a traingle free graph of chromatic number m?

Comment: It is a classical result that there are graphs with arbitarily large girth and chromatic number, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girth_(graph_theory) for a brief discussion.

Comment: @user93620 Also take a look at the Mycielski construction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycielskian